# Multiple search options, core data fetchrequest xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, search, core-data, predicate

Ok, so basically i have a core data database with customer information in. I have a searchbar also. I want it so i can select whether to search name, address, etc.etc.etc.

Here is the code i have at the moment:

```
 [sosdRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(AccountCode contains[cd] %@           
AND %d>0) AND (CompanyName contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (Address1 contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) 
AND (Address2 contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (Town contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0)  AND (County 
contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (Postcode contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (UserField01 
contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (UserField02 contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (UserField03 
contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0) AND (UserField04 contains[cd] %@  AND %d>0) AND (UserField05 
contains[cd] %@ AND %d>0)",searchBar.text, _searchAccountCodeOnly, searchBar.text, 
_searchNameOnly, searchBar.text, _searchAddress, searchBar.text, _searchAddress, 
searchBar.text, _searchTown, searchBar.text, _searchCounty, searchBar.text, _searchAddress, 
searchBar.text, _searchUser1, searchBar.text, _searchUser2, searchBar.text, _searchUser3, 
searchBar.text, _searchUser4, searchBar.text, _searchUser5]];
```

So with this, '_searchAddress' '_searchNameOnly' etc.etc. are integers. If i have say

```
_searchAccountCodeOnly = 0;
_searchNameOnly = 0;
_searchNumbers = 0;
_searchTown =  0;
_searchCounty = 0;
_searchAddress = 2;
_searchContact = 0;
_searchUser1 = 0;
_searchUser2 = 0;
_searchUser3 = 0;
_searchUser4 = 0;
_searchUser5 = 0;
```

my search will still return based on CompanyName. This is driving me insane and i'm about to run on my lunchbreak to clear my head a tad but if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that actually works (and how effective Core Data/sqlite is with optimizing such a query), but to ignore one attribute in the query you probably mean

```
(CompanyName contains[cd] %@ OR %d == 0)
```

so that the subexpression evaluates to TRUE if the corresponding flag is zero.

A better way would be to build an array of predicates with the queries that you actually need and then use

```
[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:arrayOfPredicates];
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to this programming malarkey so i will try both methods, bare with me :)  Thinking about it wouldn't the OR command mean that it would return all values it d==0 ?

Comment: Also, not sure i can completely understand how to use nscompoundpredicate, i'm looking at the apple dev docs but i'm feeling more and more stupid by the minute >.<

Comment: @Craig: If `_searchNameOnly == 0` then `(CompanyName contains[cd] %@ OR %d == 0)` evaluates to TRUE, but all other `(XXX contains[cd] %@ OR %d == 0)` expressions are still evaluated. I thought that this is want you want. You can try it and give more detailed information if it does not work.

Comment: @Craig: Is only one of the flags (_searchAccountCodeOnly, _searchNameOnly, _searchNumbers, ...) set and all others are zero? If more than one flag is set, what exactly should the search do?

Comment: Having it with OR %d==0 just returns all values. I would like it so that if an int is set to >0 (i.e 2) then it will search that column. If int is set to 0 it wont search that column. So you could either search for just account code, or account code and company name. Ty for all your help here!

Comment: @Craig: I think that `NSCompoundPredicate` is the right way to go.  I will give you a code example later, because I'm busy with other things right now.

Comment: Ok, ty :] will hopefully sort it out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16791/discussion-between-martin-r-and-craig)